# Tools for learning Finite Element Method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, finite-element-method

I'm a graduating Mechanical Engineering Technology student. I've had Calc 1, 2, 3 and differential equations & linear algebra.

I'd like to brush up on my math skills and dive into learning the finite element method. I'd like to start with structural problems (moving towards projects such as a welded tube motorcycle frame) and then delve into things like electromagnetics and CFD. (Electrical machine design and turbine design.)

While I do want to learn it for fun, I also want to learn it in such a way that it becomes a valuable tool for solving real problems.

My main computer is a Macbook running 10.10.

Can someone suggest tools and resources to begin this study?

I will note that I have had a semester of Fortran. I don't believe I will need the sheer speed so I am not at all married to using it. I'd prefer something quick to implement.

Thank you
Luke

Comment: Why bother? Just start with spectral methods, they incorporate finite methods and converge much faster. I would suggest you read Boyd's "Chebyshev and Fourier Spectral Methods".

Comment: Hey Mattos! I'm all for better methods. I'll check it out. You may have saved me years of work! :)

In my first looks at FEM I feel I have enough background to get started. Is spectral going to require a higher level of mathematics and programming experience?

Comment: No problem, if you are looking for another book to start off with I would suggest Trefethen's "Approximation Theory and Approximation Practice", although I would read Boyds book first.

Comment: See [scicomp.se], especially [Modern resources for learning FEM](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/1445)

Comment: Spectral methods do not converge quickly in the presence of discontinuities. In Mech E, there generally are.

Comment: Check out http://mooseframework.org/ for how to do some finite elements; you won't have to learn to code.